# How to convert coredata model to swift struct model?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i have a coredata objects (subclasses of NSManagedObject), i want to convert to them into Model objects , so that i can reuse existing code. How can i manually map them ?

model objects are struct like below:
i have fetched coredata entity object. but now when i am trying to map them to video struct below.
let video : Video = Video(from: <#Decoder#>)
what should i pass in decoder ?

```
struct Video: Decodable{
     var id : Int?
      var name : String?
      var video_description : String?
      var thumbnail_image_url : String?
      var provider_name : String?


    private enum VideoKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case video_description = "description"
        case thumbnail_image_url = "poster"
        case provider_details = "custom_fields"
    }

    private enum ProviderKeys : String, CodingKey{
        case provider_name = "provider"
    }

     init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        if let videoContainer = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: VideoKeys.self){

            self.id = try videoContainer.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
            self.name = try videoContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)

            self.video_description = try videoContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .video_description)

            self.thumbnail_image_url = try videoContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .thumbnail_image_url)

            if let providercontainer = try? videoContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ProviderKeys.self, forKey: .provider_details){
                self.provider_name = try providercontainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .provider_name)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: one approach is,  create your own custom init with a single parameter, which is type of coreData class.

Comment: is it a good practise to follow that way ?

Comment: it is totally depend on requirements. According to me, right now it is a good approach to achieve your requirement.

Comment: is there any other better approach for mapping between data model and coredata managed objects ?

Comment: because i have already data model setup  in code. now i am adding coredata feature into it. if i can map between coredata and data model classes then i can reuse existing code.